# Output Batch File Results to Text File AND to the screen itself

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd, text-files

I've got a Mass IP address pinger written in a Batch File that reads IP's in a Text File and then tells the user on the CMD screen if the IP is "OK" or "Failed to respond"...

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (iplist.txt) do ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo %%a ok)     || (echo %%a failed to respond)
Pause
```

It all works fine, except I would like to also output whats on the CMD screen to a text file...

All the solutions on Stackoverflow make the output on the CMD screen NOT show but instead make all the output go directly to the Text File.

**I need it to show the output on BOTH the CMD screen and on the Text File.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to write to both places

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("iplist.txt") do (
        ping -n 1 "%%~a" >nul && set "msg=%%~a ok" || set "msg=%%~a failed to respond"
        >con echo(!msg!
        echo(!msg!
    )) > "logfile.txt"
    Pause
```

You can see the first `echo` is redirected to the console. The second one has no redirection, the full `for` command has been redirected to avoid a open/close operation on the output file for each line write.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, also If you dont mind, can you explain what  echo(!msg!  does?

Comment: @CrazyRussianHacker, the `!msg!` is a delayed reference to `%msg%` variable (better read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28832515/2861476), comments are very limited). `echo(` is the same `echo` command, but the parenthesis trick avoids some non always desired behaviours (ex.  the `ECHO is off` string when echoing empty lines)